# 2-dimensional array, IF condition checking

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've came across a problem when coding with C++ 2D array.
Just a little question, what does the code below mean?

```
...

if(array[x][y] >= 9){

...

}

...
```

Does that mean when the sum of x and y of the array is greater or equal to 9, then only the body of the IF will run? Or ........?

Please explain and provide some simply examples.

Answer (score 1):

the array is two dimensional, it means the element at `array[x][y]`

unlike 1D arrays, which only require 1 index, 2D arrays require 2 indices in the form of `array[x][y]` presumably in a nested for loop.

You can iterate through such an array like this

```
for (int x = 0; x < arrayLength; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < array[x]Length; y++) {

    // do something with array[x][y]

    }  
}
```

where arrayLength is the length of array and array[x] length is the length of array[x].

So in reference to the code that you posted, it's testing to see if the member of the 2D array is greater than or equal to 9.

Answer (score 1):

Ok let's start with the basics.

**1D Arrays**

How can you imagine a normal array? You could say a normal array is like a number line:

```
|-------------------------------| where every - is one element in your array
```

The very first '-' on the left side is the element at myArray[0] (the '|' are just symbolizing that it has a start and a end).

**2D Arrays**

A 2D array can be visualized as checkerboard, bookshelf or a table with columns and rows.

```
|-------------------------------|
|-------------------------------|
|-------------------------------|
|-------------------------------|
```

Just like in chess you need 2 values in order to address an element. If you only specify one value the compiler might know the row of your value but not its column (or the other way around). That means you need x and y coordinates (which is a visual analogy for a coordinate system). In order to address a value you have to do it like this:

myArray[x][y] where x could be the row of our checkerboard and y the column.

In your case your 2D array is most likely filled with integers. The 'if' statement checks if the value stored in myArray[x][y] is larger than 9. If myArray[x][y] is larger than 9 this statement returns true and the code inside will get executed.

After executing the code inside of the 'if' statement the program will continue to execute the code after the if statement. 2D arrays can be understood as an array containing arrays.

If you are thinking 3 dimensional arrays are possible you're right. Here you need 3 coordinates in order to describe a point since you have depth, height and length (here I'm talking about the visual length not the length in terms of total amount of elements.).

I don't know whether this helped but this is of course a very visual approach of explaining how multi-dimensional arrays work.

**Example**

```
int myArray[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3},   // row 0
                     {4, 5, 6},   // row 1
                     {7, 8, 10}}; // row 2
```

In this case your if statement would only be executed if x = 2 and y = 2 since myArray[2][2] = 10

Answer (score 0):

It means "IF the element at coordinates (x,y) is greater or equal than 9...".

There is no addition operation. The array is probably declared with the minimum dimensions (x+1, y+1).

```
    int array[2][2] = {{12, 6}, {3, -2}};

    int x=1, y=0;

    if(array[x][y] >= 9){...}    // array[1][0] equals 3, condition is false
```